# Arrays with outer and inner classes

Tags: java, oop, inner-classes, outer-classes

I am relatively new to Java.  I wanted to create an arraylist of an outer class and for each index of the outer class of the arraylist I want an arraylist of inner classes.

```
public Outerclass{

    //Code Here

    public InnerClass{
    //Code Here
    }
}

//My attempt at setting up the arrays
public ArrayList <Outerclass> olist;
public ArrayList <InnerClass> ilist;


 olist= new ArrayList<Outerclass>();
 for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      Outerclass c = new Outerclass ();
      ilist = new ArrayList<InnerClass>();
      for(int j = 0 ; j < 4; j++){
          InnerClass e = new InnerClass();
          ilist.add(e);
      }
      olist.add(c);
 }
```

Will this work?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: It won't work. There needs to be the inner class array in the outer class.

Comment: how would I do that @tbodt?

Comment: Do instances of the inner class need to maintain references to members of the outer class instances? If not, make the inner class `static` and treat it as a top-level class.

Comment: @JimGarrison yes the inner class needs to maintain reference to members of the outer class instance

Answer (score 1):

First, I think that you should learn how to walk before you start running:

```
public Outerclass
```

should be

```
public class Outerclass
```

same with inner!

Second, all the last portion of your code should be in a `main()` method INSIDE Ourclass.

And third, no, you cannot use inner class like that, that's why these classes are inner. If you want to use inner classes from inside `main()` or from outside the outer class you have to use an instance of outer in order to access them, same like accessing any other instance member - you can't access it directly:

```
        Outerclass oc = new Outerclass();
        Outerclass.InnerClass in = oc.new InnerClass();
```

Comment: thank you!  I probably should have been a bit more clear when I copied my code. How would I parameterize my Arraylist for the inner class.  Would it be ArrayList<Outerclass.InnerClass> or would it be ArrayList<InnerClass>?

Answer (score 1):

A litte refinement for answer #2, if you have nested classes for data storage, means that you have an constructor for the outer class that automatically generates a variable number of array members for the inner class like a tree structure. This solution is practically a workaround which uses one defined member - an ArrayList - which can be expanded later instead of a direct definition of an InnerClass[] array inside the OuterClass, which won't work if its not static.

```
public class OuterClass
{
    private int NumberInnerClassInstances;       
    // ... other members of OuterClass
    ArrayList<InnerClass> innerClassInstances = new ArrayList<>();

    OuterClass( input vars ...)  {
        // calculate the NumberInnerClassInstances needed
        for(int i = 0 ; j < NumberInnerClassInstances; i++) {
            OuterClass.InnerClass in = this.new InnerClass(i);
            innerClassInstances.add(in);
        }
    }

    public class InnerClass
    {
        int icvar;
        InnerClass(int i) {
            //...construct the Inner Class Member #i
            // can access the members of OuterClass
        }
    }
}
```

from outside, you can then access the InnerClass Instances with get:

```
oc = new OuterClass( vars ...)
var = oc.InnerClassInstances.get(i).icvar
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the key lines of your code:

```
 Outerclass c = new Outerclass ();

     InnerClass e = new InnerClass();
```

That won't work.  You will get a compilation error.

Since `InnerClass` is an inner class, it needs to be instantiated in the context of an instance of its enclosing class (i.e. `OuterClass`).  Like this:

```
 Outerclass c = new Outerclass ();

     InnerClass e = c.new InnerClass();
```

The `c.new ...` form is called a *qualified class instance creation expression*; see [JLS 15.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9).

Notes:

1. If the code that creates the inner class is in the context of an instance of the outer class (e.g. it is in an instance method of the outer class) then you don't need to qualify the `new` like that.
2. If the `InnerClass` is `static` this isn't necessary either.  But then `InnerClass` is a nested class not an inner class ... according to the standard Java terminology.

Answer (score 0):

An instance of an inner class can only exist within an instance of an outer class. (For a distinction between static and non-static inner classes, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class/70358#70358) for more info).

What this means is that you create inner objects *within* outer objects. You can think of it as the outer objects creating and containing the inner objects (hence the name `inner`)

Here's an example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class OuterClass {
    static ArrayList<InnerClass> innerClasses = new ArrayList<InnerClass>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OuterClass oc1 = new OuterClass();
        OuterClass.InnerClass ic1 =  oc1.new InnerClass();
        OuterClass.InnerClass ic2 =  oc1.new InnerClass();
        innerClasses.add(ic1);
        innerClasses.add(ic2);      
        System.out.println(innerClasses.size());
    }
    class InnerClass {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that the `InnerClass` needs to maintain reference to the members of the `OuterClass`, I wonder why aren't you putting the `ArrayList<InnerClass>` inside `OuterClass`. If they're composed in that way it makes much more sense to have the list 'managed' by the `OuterClass` and just give it access methods to return the list of `InnerClass` instances etc.

So something like this:

```
public class OuterClass
{
   private List<InnerClass> innerClassInstances = new ArrayList<>;

   public void addInnerInstances(int count)
   {
      for(int j = 0 ; j < count; j++)
      {
         InnerClass e = new InnerClass();
         innerClassInstances.add(e);
      }
   }

   public List<InnerClass> getInnerClassInstances()
   {
       return innerClassInstances;
   }

   public class InnerClass
   {
     //...
   }
}

   //in your main class or wherever
   List<Outerclass> olist;

   olist= new ArrayList<Outerclass>();
   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
   {
      Outerclass c = new Outerclass ();
      c.addInnerInstances(4);
      olist.add(c);
   }
```

You cannot create the `InnerClass` on its own with `new` as you're doing, you are saying that it needs to access the members of its `OuterClass` instance, and as you can see in your code, for each `new InnerClass()` you are never specifying in any way what is the `OuterClass` instance for it.